# Google Cloud Messaging - upstream

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm able to send downstream data from my server to my android app.
But I can't find how to send upstream message.

On the Android side, I correctly changed the AndroidManifest.xml file because downstream messages work (did I?).

On the server side, I created my *XmppReceiverServlet* and updated the *web.xml* file accordingly and add the `<service>xmpp_message</service>` into the *appengine-web.xml*.

But, when I try to send a message from the app to the server, nothing seems to happen. The code below never triggers a POST on the server side.
(I followed this example https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream)

```
AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
String SENDER_ID = "MyGoogleDevelopersConsoleProjectId";
[...]
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    @Override
     protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
     String msg = "";
     try {
         Bundle data = new Bundle();
         data.putString("my_message", "Hello World");
         data.putString("my_action", "SAY_HELLO");
         String msgId = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet())
         gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", msgId, data);
         msg = "Sent message #" + msgId
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
     }
     return msg;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
     MyUtils.print("onPostExecute: " + msg);
     }
 }.execute(null, null, null);
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: does your server successfully connect to CCS?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not sure to understand the question :-/ I thought I had nothing to do more than waiting for a POST on the server side.

Comment: BTW, my server is an App Engine Java Server.

Comment: I see, missed the app engine part. Could you try using <your-app-name>@appspot.com instead of SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com"?

Comment: Thanks Arthur for the answer, but it did change anything, still nothing on the doPost of my servlet. Why is it so simple to push notifications from up there and so twisted to send some stuff from down there?!!?